# subvertpy install with reviewboard on SUSE

Tags: linux, apache, review-board

i installed subvertpy, and looks successfully.
Searching for subvertpy
Best match: subvertpy 0.9.1
Processing subvertpy-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg
subvertpy 0.9.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing subvertpy-fast-export script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/subvertpy-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for subvertpy
Finished processing dependencies for subvertpy

but when i tried to add a svn repository, it shows

The Python module "subvertpy" is not installed.You may need to restart the server after installing it.

is there anything i should configure in apache???

Answer (score 0):

Install pysvn

```
apt-get install subversion python-svn
```

or

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install pysvn
```

also you can try

```
sudo yum install -y subversion-devel
wget http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.6.tar.gz
tar xf pysvn-1.7.6.tar.gz
(cd pysvn-1.7.6; cd Source;python setup.py backport;python setup.py configure;make;)
# copy
PythonLib="/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pysvn"
sudo mkdir -p ${PythonLib}
sudo cp pysvn-1.7.6/Source/pysvn/__init__.py ${PythonLib}
sudo cp pysvn-1.7.6/Source/pysvn/_pysvn*.so ${PythonLib}
```